# Three.js : Gltf object adding material to look better

Tags: three.js, textures, shadow, gltf

I'm actually trying to add some materials to my Gltf objects in three js r113, but I don't know how to use correctly material parameters and the light as I see my object in three js viewer. This is What I get in Firefox

[image]

and this is what I'm dreaming about

[image: Window10 3D viewer].

I guess this is the value I need to apply to my code

[image: glTF Viewer]

This is how I add my gltf and how I try to add materials :

```
// Load a glTF resource of FENCE 
  gltfLoader.load( 'Fence.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    fenceModel = gltf.scene;
    // fenceModel.traverse(function (child) {
    // if (child.isMesh) {
    //     child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    //         color: 0xc07341, //light Brown
    //         reflectivity: 0,
    //         dithering: true
    //     });
    //   }
    // });
  });

  var ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5 );
  scene.add( ambientlight );
```

Actually my floor is only a gltf file with no materials.
Maybe I need to add some shadow porperties to my floor and then I could see the fence shadow ?
I need some help to understand how to do a better light effect on object.
Thank you, sorry for my english I'm using translator to help me.

Ps: My gltf object contain texture in it.

Comment: I suggest you start by setting the [outputEncoding](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.outputEncoding) of your renderer to `THREE.sRGBEncoding`. Besides, try to add a directional light next to your ambient light. Or one step further, try to add a HDR environment map like in the following official example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf

Comment: @Mugen87 Thank you for your answer, I just added a directional light on the left side of the fence and it's better. I added this line too but i don't see any change :  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;  If I understand it's for a better render of my object using RGB ? I will try to see for the HDR enviroment map later it seem more complicated.